# Getting a domain name off of the blacklist

Tags: domain, blacklist

I have a friend who purchased a domain name recently that he found out (after buying it) is apparently blocked by many corporate firewalls or proxies b/c it's been tagged as porn by the blacklist db they're using.

Are there any common agencies he can appeal to in order to get the domain name off the black lists?

It's not just one corporation, either, he's looking at marketing a subscription-based service to a certain industry, so any contacting a particular firewall/proxy admin and have them manually update the blacklist won't scale well.

Thanks in advance.
Paul

Comment: This would be better suited to ServerFault.

Comment: +1, this could be a good reference in the future :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When we found ourselves categorized incorrectly in several blacklists a few months ago, we had to contact each one individually to appeal. Some useful addresses:

- https://www.trustedsource.org/ (McAfee)
- suggest@websense.com (Websense)
- http://www.fortiguard.com/webfiltering/webfiltering.html (FortiGuard)
- http://domain.opendns.com (OpenDNS)

Comment: McAfee also has SiteAdvisor: http://www.siteadvisor.com/ It probably wouldn't hurt to add a "site owner" comment there.

Answer (score 1):

[Emailreg](http://www.emailreg.org) is one of the services we used to get our email domain off a number of blacklists.  It seems a popular search list for [Barracuda Networks](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/?L=en) equipment. A number of our customers were using their gear and rejecting our email. Going through that service and getting validated removed a lot of our roadblocks.